# Transform a large integer to Plaintext ERROR in SEAL Library

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, implementation, encoding

In SEAL library, I want to multiply a BFV ciphertext *ct* with an integer *inverse*. Here are what I do:

1. Compute the integer *inverse* as follows:

> ```
> uint64_t inverse = invert_mod(pow(2, log_total_item),enc_params_.plain_modulus());
> ```

2. Encode *inverse* to BFV plaintext using the following code:

> ```
> Plaintext inverse_pt(to_string(inverse));
> ```

3. Compute multiplication as follows:

> ```
> evaluator.Multiply_plain_inplace(*ct*, *inverse_pt*);
> ```

But the value of *inverse* is too large:

```
enc_params_.plain_modulus() = 1152921504606830593 
inverse = 1134907106097348865
```

Error occurs in step 2 like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  hex_poly has too large coefficients
```

It seems that *inverse* is too large and can not be transformed to BFV plaintext directly. I want to know is there any method that can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know: if you are trying to multiply a ciphertext by a very large constant (*inverse*, I assume), this is a highly nontrivial task (because of the simultaneous error scale-up). In fact, if you're able to do that, you already did the essential part of bootstrapping itself (check e.g. [Section 3, first paragraph and following](https://eprint.iacr.org/2021/691.pdf)).

Now, that's what might be the reason, why you get an error message here.